# QGIS refactor field in processing modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am trying to create a model to standardize data received from various clients into one single output format.
To do so, I use the refactor field and field mapper, following the answer given here: [Using fields mapper in QGIS Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292324/how-to-use-fields-mapper-in-qgis-modeler)

One vector input is the client layer (unformatted)

Another vector input is our company standard layer (formatted)

Then the model becomes as follow.

[image: Model]

The problem is that when I want to select in the list of "Source expression" my field from the client, I cannot find it. I only have the field from the formated layer available (see below).
When I do it using the algorithm directly from the processing toolbox, it is working well.

Am I missing something ?

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.14.16

---

@MrXsquared’s method doesn't allow the user to choose for each field of "client layer" which one is matching with the field of "company layer".

My goal is to reproduce the effect of Small ETL plugin (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yISFnyYCbqs&feature=youtu.be ) by using only the processing modeler (I want to share a project template to colleagues with the model saved in the template to avoid installing plugin).

I found a workaround: for each field, request the user to select it in the list and then rename it as the model, then refactor.

See the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For `refactor fields` you can only choose **one** input layer. You need to add `refactor fields` tool **twice**. If you want, you can then merge the two outputs afterwards, like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question based on your answer.